# using constructor for form ,pass all datas from gidview to another form's gridview c#?

Tags: c#, gridview

i want to pass all datas from one gridview to another form's gridview using constructor i have tried many codes that does'nt work .
in the first form:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int b = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
    {
        Form8 f = new Form8(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(),
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString(),
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString(),
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString(),
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString(),
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString(),
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString(),
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value.ToString());
        if (i == 8)

        break;
        f.Show();
    }

}
```

In next form:

```
public partial class Form8 : Form
{
    public Form8(string id,string name,string gender,string address,string place,string phoneno,string username,string password)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       /// dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        Form2 frm=new Form2();
        int b=frm.dataGridView1.RowCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < b-1; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = id;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = name;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value = gender;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value = address;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = place;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value = phoneno;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = username;
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = password;
        }
    }   
}
```

it does'nt work well. it showing no of forms that showing one row in each form? pleas help .i am a beginer in programming 
.thak you in aduance

data source to gridview1

```
    private DataView GetData()
    {
        string selectQry = "select (id) as [Id], (name) as [Name],(gender)as [Gender],(address)as [Address],(place)as [place],(phoneno) as[mob],(username)as[User_name],(password)as[PWD],(photo) as[photo] from tbl_reg1";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataView tableView = null;
        try
        {

            conn = new SqlConnection(constrg.constr);
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand tempCom = new SqlCommand(selectQry, conn);

            da.SelectCommand = tempCom;
            da.Fill(ds);
            tableView = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        return tableView;
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetData();

    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you set the `datasource` to `dataGridView1` ?

Comment: What you need is reusing the datasource.

Comment: Replace this `public Form8(string id,string name,string gender,string address,string place,string phoneno,string username,string password)` with `public Form2Form8(string id,string name,string gender,string address,string place,string phoneno,string username,string password):this(){}`

Comment: i gave the data source sir @HariPrasad

Answer (score 1):

Since you need entire `DataGridView1` in other `Form`, you could get the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView1` in `MainForm` and pass it to other form.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dataView = (DataView)dataGridView1.DataSource;
    var table = dataView.Take(8)              // Since you want only 8 rows
                        .CopyToDataTable();   // Creates new DataTable

    Form8 f = new Form8(table); 
    f.Show();
}
```

Now in other form (`Form8`) just set the source.

```
public partial class Form8 : Form
{
    public Form8(DataTable data)
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
        dataGridView1.DataSource =table;
    }   
}
```

Comment: No problem, please mark it as an answer if you happy about it.